# Nginx, https and websocket chat not working with Django

Tags: python, django, nginx, https, websocket

after adding the SSL certificates successfully, the certificate is blocking the python scripts that uses websockets library in our website's chat.

Has anyone experienced anything similar?

Thanks

Comment: I remember I faced this issue long back, Can you please update your question with websocket configuration from Nginx?.

Comment: @Murali by any chance you still having that websocket configuration somewhere? That would help a lot!